# Soundcloud ajax response not reached

Tags: javascript, ajax, soundcloud

I'm executing this query to get an user in SoundCloud.
I can see that the call is correctly done in Chrome network tab, after a click, however, it doesn't reach the javascript alert. So I can't retrieve the JSON response and add it to the DOM.

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: '067320efe29b7da263fd8bb093911116',
    redirect_uri: 'trofeosbalbino.com/beonerecords'
});

$("#embedTrack").click(function() {
    SC.get('/users', {q: 'beonerecords'}, function (users) {
      alert(users);  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors in your console?

Comment: No...nothing at all in the console...

Comment: Use `.then(function()` instead of `, function ()` as stated in the docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks and your code will work fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqbeEw (check console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the SoundCloud API in a client side web application, you should use the `SC.connect()` method to authenticate the application. Try something such as the following:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '067320efe29b7da263fd8bb093911116',
  redirect_uri: 'http://trofeosbalbino.com/beonerecords'
});

$("#embedTrack").click(function() {
    SC.connect().then(function(){
      SC.get('/users', {q: 'beonerecords'}, function (users) {
        return users;
      });
    }).then(function(users){
      alert(users);
    });
});
```